Powershell adding to Microsoft365 group error
I am adding a list of users from PS to microsoft 365 groups using this:
`Connect-ExchangeOnline
#PowerShell to Import Members to office 365 group from CSV
Import-CSV "myfile.csv" | ForEach-Object {
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity "thegroup" -LinkType Members -Links $_.Member
Write-host -f Green "Added Member '$($_.Member)' to Office 365 Group 'DeliveryCTI'"
}

#Disconnect Exchange Online
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline `

User was added in M365 group; however, it continuously runs and shows this error
`Added Member 'mmm@mydomain.com' to Office 365 Group 'thegroup'
Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Links'. Cannot       convert value "System.String[]" to type 
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter[]". Error: "Parameter values     of type 
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter can't be empty. Specify a    value, and try again.
Parameter name: identity"
At C:\Users\michael.z\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_bg20jn4o.302\tmpEXO_bg20jn4o.302.psm1:1204     char:13
+             Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-UnifiedGroupLinks], ParameterTransformationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=AS5PR09MB6674,RequestId=fbb7c91a-135f-bd25-1445-    fbfec2a0b8a3,TimeStamp=Tue, 07 May 2024 20:20:19 GMT],Write-Err 

orMessage
Added Member '' to Office 365 Group 'DeliveryCTI'
Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Links'. Cannot     convert value "System.String[]" to type 
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter[]". Error: "Parameter values of type 
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter can't be empty. Specify a value, and try again.
Parameter name: identity"
At C:\Users\michael.z\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_bg20jn4o.302\tmpEXO_bg20jn4o.302.psm1:1204   char:13
 +             Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
 +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-UnifiedGroupLinks],     ParameterTransformationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=AS5PR09MB6674,RequestId=13c37754-0fd9-2b03-e805-bd88e2afbc22,TimeStamp=Tue, 07 May 2024 20:20:20 GMT],Write-Err 

orMessage
`
How to stop the continous running and fix the error?
CSV file contains only Members header.
Thanks
I am expecting it will not produce any error and prevent adding a blank member to the m365 group

What is/are the CSV headers? Is there a ‘Member’ column? Without knowing details of how the CSV is formatted, it will be difficult to make recommendations.

I put the Member column only as header, it contains email addresses. It works and added the user in the M365 groups. but I do not know where the error is coming from, if I missed something or need to add column headers in the csv.

Please add the output of the following command to the question. Get-Content -Path myfile.csv -First 3

@lit, I am getting to long to paste the output here. I am sorry, first time to use stackoverflow. is it possible to paste an image instead?

already got it working. just need to clear the csv with notepad. My additional question is how can I check or what script should I use to check if the user exist already, and it will show already exist and will not add. And where to put the script. Thanks @lit, Doug

I am not sure what you mean by "too long to paste the output...". Three (3) lines is unlikely to be "too long." While it is possible to paste an image into a question or answer, it should only be done when there is no other way. Code and text data should never be a picture. It prevents the reader from using it to test an answer. The goal should be to make it as easy as possible for the reader to understand and answer the question.
